# How to iterate on a dynamic FormControl with Angular2 and FormBuilder?

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to iterate in the HTML part over a FormControl which was dynamically generated, but I get **[object Object],[object Object]** in the input field.

The Data:
I get a json string with following format:

```
{
    "security_groups": {
        "databaseName1": [{
            "destination": "10.0.8.1-10.0.8.255",
            "ports": "27000-27499",
            "protocol": "tcp"
        }, {
            "destination": "10.0.8.1-10.0.8.255",
            "ports": "27000-27499",
            "protocol": "tcp"
        }],
        "xyz": [{
            "destination": "10.0.8.1-10.0.8.255",
            "ports": "27000-27499",
            "protocol": "tcp"
        }]
    }
}
```

this json is is just fix in the structure but not in the naming.
Database1 can also by called differently. Just the key "security_groups" is fix.

I have in my controller following code:

```
public form: FormGroup;
  public data: any;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.dataSet[this.key];

    this.form = this._fb.group({});
    Object.keys(this.data).forEach(name => {
      this.form.addControl(name, new FormControl(
        this.data[name], [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(1)]
      ));
    });
```

When I check now this in the console, I get following structure.

```
FormGroup
  ...
  controls: Object
    databaseName1: FormControl
    ...
    _value: Array[2]
      0: Object
        destination: "10.0.8.1-10.0.8.255"
        ports: "27000-27499"
        protocol: "tcp"
        __proto__: Object
      1: Object
        destination: "10.0.8.1-10.0.8.255"
        ports: "27000-27499"
        protocol: "tcp"
        __proto__: Object
        ...
    xyz: FormControl
    ...
    _value: Array[2]
      0: Object
        destination: "10.0.8.1-10.0.8.255"
        ports: "27000-27499"
        protocol: "tcp"
        __proto__: Object
        ...
```

I have a FormControlName = "databaseName1", and I have a FormControlName = "xyz".
I tray now to iterate over this FormControls (databaseName1 and xyz) and put there name in a input field.

The HTML Code so far:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSave(form)">
  <div *ngFor="let control of form.controls | keyVal; let i=index">

    control.log(control.key)

    <input class="form-control" [formControlName]=control.key>
  </div>
</form>
```

The values of "control.key" are databaseName1 and xyz check in console.
The input field shows the value [object Object],[object Object].

How it's possible to write the FormControlName in the input field?

Is that way of create the form in the controller wrong?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your `input` to the objects `databaseName1` and `xyz`. The input shows the value returned by calling `toString` on the passed property, thus in this case it returns `[object Object]`.

Let's assume you actually want to bind to the properties of a single object. For sake of simplicity I leave out the validators from my example. I'll leave the HTML up to you.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.data = this.dataSet[this.key];

  this.form = this._fb.group({});

  let self = this; //multiple fat-arrow functions, so capture this.
  Object.keys(this.data).forEach(name => { //databaseName1 and xyz
    let array = self.data[name];
    array.forEach(item => { //The objects within the arrays referenced by databaseName1 and xyz.
      self.form.addControl(name, new FormGroup({
        destination: new FormControl(item['destination']),
        ports: new FormControl(item['ports']),
        protocol: new FormControl(item['protocol'])
      }));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: that works, however, the value for e.g databaseName1 is not an array.

Comment: According to the JSON provided in your question, databaseName1 is an array. Thus, I can't really help you any further with that.